# angularjs ng-bind-html not working with twimoji

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, unicode, emoji

AngularJS `ng-bind-html` not working with [twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji) and [angular-twemoji](https://github.com/scheffield/angular-twemoji)

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['sc.twemoji'])
  .controller('mycontroller', function($scope, twemoji) {
    $scope.myemojis = [{
      'unicode': '1f600',
      'category': 'people',
    }, {
      'unicode': '1f62c',
      'category': 'people',
    }, {
      'unicode': '1f601',
      'category': 'people',
    }, {
      'unicode': '1f602',
      'category': 'people',
    }, {
      'unicode': '1f603',
      'category': 'people',
    }, {
      'unicode': '1f604',
      'category': 'people',
    }, {
      'unicode': '1f605',
      'category': 'people',
    }, {
      'unicode': '1f606',
      'category': 'people',
    }, {
      'unicode': '1f607',
      'category': 'people',
    }, {
      'unicode': '1f609',
      'category': 'people',
    }, {
      'unicode': '1f60a',
      'category': 'people',
    }, {
      'unicode': '1f642',
      'category': 'people',
    }, {
      'unicode': '1f643',
      'category': 'people',
    }, {
      'unicode': '263a',
      'category': 'peopl'
    }]
  })
  .filter('prefixEmoji', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
      val = "&#x" + val;
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
  })
  .filter('fixEmoji', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
      val = "0x" + val;
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(String.fromCodePoint(val));
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//twemoji.maxcdn.com/twemoji.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/scheffield/angular-twemoji/master/dist/angular-twemoji.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mycontroller">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>Emoji with '&#x' fix</th>
      <th>Twemoji not working</th>
      <th>Emoji with '0x' fix</th>
      <th>Twemoji not working</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ol>
          <li ng-repeat="myemoji in myemojis" ng-bind-html="myemoji.unicode | prefixEmoji"></li>
        </ol>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ol>
          <li ng-repeat="myemoji in myemojis" ng-bind-html="myemoji.unicode | prefixEmoji | twemoji"></li>
        </ol>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ol>
          <li ng-repeat="myemoji in myemojis" ng-bind-html="myemoji.unicode | fixEmoji"></li>
        </ol>
      </td>
      <td>
        <ol>
          <li ng-repeat="myemoji in myemojis" ng-bind-html="myemoji.unicode | fixEmoji | twemoji"></li>
        </ol>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the $sanitize service as per the angular docs:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

You controller code would become:

```
.controller('mycontroller', function($scope, $sanitize, twemoji) {
```

NOTE: As per the docs: "In order to use ngSanitize in your module's dependencies, you need to include "angular-sanitize.js" in your application"

So you would possibly include this script reference, really depends on how you have this set-up:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your fiddle is giving this error so clearly something is wrong there but I was not able to resolve the issue. Perhaps this use is not supported by the wrapper provided.


    TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
        at grabAllTextNodes (twemoji.min.js:2)
        at parseNode (twemoji.min.js:2)
        at Object.parse (twemoji.min.js:2)

Comment: I was having this same issue. I fixed it by passing in the unicode emoji icon directly. Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/51pggkwy/3/

Here is my ngrepeat: '<li data-ng-repeat="emoji in emojiList | filter:searchTerms" data-ng-click="searchWithEmoji(emoji.Annotations,emoji.Description);" data-ng-bind-html="emoji.Unicode | twemoji"></li>'   here is the site with this working: http://emojinewssearch.com/

Comment: I am unable to use emoji icons because backend teams are sending emoji unicode.